# SVN and GIT parallel

Tags: svn, github

I am working on a code based project. I am using SVN with my private server and I use TRAC for ticketing and project management. 
Parallel I would like to pull my code to github for discussions and the open source thought.

First a commit changes to my svn server and afterwards to github. I have ignored the .git/* Files in svn and vice versa. 
But I always get merge errors while pushing to github.

Does anyone have experiences in using both services and can give my hints? 
Yours, Raphael

Comment: Do you plan to get changes from GitHub (e.g. apply Pull requests or push code to GitHub and only then apply it to your SVN) or do you want to use it just in write-only manner? In the first case I wouldn't recommend you to use 2 remotes in one git-svn repository ([why?](http://gitsvn.x10.mx/?p=153) --- because "git svn dcommit" adds "git-svn-id:" signature to commits).

Answer (score 2):

Just use git-svn (**one** local codebase - Git repo) and have two remote: SVN and Git